# SBT Constant OutOfMemory on Jenkins Job

Tags: java, jenkins, playframework, sbt, out-of-memory

We have Jenkins setup for running jobs for a project our team is currently working on but we are having problems with the jobs crashing constantly due to an `OutOfMemory`.

The Jenkins environment is running on a virtual machine. The machine it is on has fairly decent specs and doesn't have to many VMs on it. Our SBT jobs run in a separate jobs list which has 8GB of RAM available.

Project build.properties `sbt.version=0.13.9`

Jenkins ver. 2.6

We are executing the following command for the job:

```
/usr/java/default/bin/java -Xmx2G -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar /usr/local/sbt/default/bin/sbt-launch.jar compile test:compile test universal:publish
```

Which produces the following throughout the log:

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-40" java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2626)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1321)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestRunner$Skeleton$1$React.react(Framework.scala:945)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestRunner$Skeleton$1.run(Framework.scala:934)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "Thread-29" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2321)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2614)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2624)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1321)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at sbt.React.react(ForkTests.scala:114)
        at sbt.ForkTests$$anonfun$mainTestTask$1$Acceptor$2$.run(ForkTests.scala:74)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The dump file the job produces [here](http://pastebin.com/EM3qva5C) (pastebin.com/EM3qva5C)

We have tried different variations of the java args but all have come to the same result so we are wondering if there is something else wrong/what we need to change to prevent the builds from failing?

Answer (score 1):

Your tests are working in a forked JVM, so you have to provide more memory to them.

Add the following line to `build.sbt`:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx1G")
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. Attempted this with no luck. I have been doing some further testing and disabled fork with more ram etc but still no luck. I have noticed that its only during the tests that it fails though.

We have a mutli module project so i decided to run each sub modules tests in seqence giving the following:
`compile test:compile module1/test module2/test module3/test module4/test module5/test module6/test module7/test module8/test module9/test`

This passed fine but if i just run:
`compile test:compile test`
It fails